# Load PHP view file from controller with given parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I have a simple controller file **StudentController.php**

```
<?php

$data = array();
$data["firstName"] = $_GET["firstName"];

loadView("StudentView.php", $data);

?>
```

I have a even simpler view file called **StudentView.php**

```
<?php

echo $firstName;

?>
```

I have absolutely no idea how to implement `loadView($view, $data)` function. I want variables from `$data` in controller became available in view (`$data["foo"]` from controller became `$foo` in view)

I want achieve what is very easy to do in [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) but I have no idea how it is implemented. I tried to look into Controller.php and Loader.php in source files, but it was too messy for me to understand.

I don't want to use CodeIgniter or any other framework, I want to natively do in PHP.

Comment: What you have there is not MVC. It's only the basic separation of mostly-html template from php-based logic. This is based on the same underlaying [principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) as MVC, but that's only thing that you code has in common with above mentioned design pattern.

Comment: I know that, I now this is not MVC, I was trying to come up with example as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be building a large website to be used by the general public, a framework is generally a good idea for multiple reasons:

- Properly unit tested - generally speaking, you can be confident that the core of your website is functioning as it's intended to
- Community support - have questions and you can easily get answers; generally these frameworks are open sourced and usually actively developed by the PHP community
- Secure - Framework developers are, well, framework developers; and they have been trained to write code with security as a top priority

However, this question has nothing to do with frameworks vs not, so I'll answer the question you asked with a very simple function:

```
function loadView($view, $data) {
    extract($data);
    ob_start();
    require_once $view;
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $contents;
}
```

You can chose to return the contents or print them directly, but that function should do what you need. I'm making no guarantees about the security of this code, and I have obviously done no error checking. But it should serve as a great foundation to get you started.

Comment: wow, I wasn't expecting to be this simple, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks ;)

I'm not trying to build a huge web-site, I'm just trying to understand how PHP and CodeIgniter work, but thanks for the advice, I will keep it in mind ;)

Comment: Please, stop confusing views with [templates](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html).

Comment: Then maybe you should drop the pretense that this is "MVC". What you have there is not a view. Only a **poorly implemented** template, which was my original point.

Comment: Where in the world did I imply that this is MVC in the slightest? I used the function name `loadView` exactly as the OP did, after stating the benefits of using a true framework. Get over it and move on with your life. Thanks for the useless down vote - that should remind me to go around and down vote your posts for absolutely no reason now